# How to rewrite regexp without positive look-ahead?

Tags: regex, rust, regex-lookarounds, positive-lookahead

The regex `[^a-z0-9%*][a-z0-9%]{3,}(?=[^a-z0-9%*])` is not supported by Rust's default [`regex` create](https://crates.io/crates/regex) due to positive look-ahead (`?=`):

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
regex parse error:
    [^a-z0-9%*][a-z0-9%]{3,}(?=[^a-z0-9%*])
                            ^^^
error: look-around, including look-ahead and look-behind, is not supported
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
)
```

What's the optimal way to rewrite it or make it working?

I've found [`fancy-regex` crate](https://crates.io/crates/fancy-regex) but i'd like to avoid using both crates (or prefer fancy over default) just for one missing feature.

PS. here it is at least one expected matches [example](https://regex101.com/r/6j4EZk/1).

Comment: You may try: `([^a-z0-9%*][a-z0-9%]{3,})[^a-z0-9%*]` and use acpture group #1

Comment: Edit your question and show samples of what should (and should not) match.

Comment: Edited my question with at least 1 example. The rest tbd

Comment: Just stick with `[^a-z0-9%*][a-z0-9%]{3,}` and leave lookahead out.

Answer (score 3):

Place your current matching pattern into a capture group, and also match (but do not capture) the term currently inside the lookahead:

```regex
([^a-z0-9%*][a-z0-9%]{3,})(?:[^a-z0-9%*]|$)
```

Comment: can you please explain ".. and also match (but do not capture) .."? Eventually i need to extract all matches from the string, eg. from `^asdf^1234^56as^` i need to extract 3 matches (`^asdf`, `^1234` and `^56as`)

Comment: It works a bit different from original one for `^asdf^1234^56as^` for example. The original one finds 3 matches (`^asdf`, `^1234` and `^56as`) and the new one only 2 matches (`^asdf` and `^56as`), so the idea seems to be right, but not fully equal

Comment: I think your pattern is wrong.  Edit your question and include some data.

Comment: the original https://regex101.com/r/6j4EZk/1 and the new one https://regex101.com/r/yqTvJf/1. I do have the tests but i need to refine them. I got the idea and i think if we fix the difference between the links it will be enough for me. Thanks

Comment: @4ntoine: You cannot get 3 matches without using lookahead

Comment: @anubhava what would be your recommendation? Currently i'm thinking about implementing it programmatically (eg. find the matches and check the look-ahead part programmatically)

Comment: I recommend making this a complete question by including sample data and then explaining the logic for what you want to match.